# Strategies for solving the infinite integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{k}{k^2+\alpha^2} \, J_0(k) J_0(kr) \, \mathrm{d}k $ where $r \ge 0$ and $\alpha > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, improper-integrals, bessel-functions

While conducting an analysis of an inverse Fourier transform stemming from a fluid mechanics problem related to flows in porous media, I encountered the following infinite integral:
$$
f(r) = \int_0^\infty \frac{k}{k^2+\alpha^2} \, J_0(k) J_0(kr) \, \mathrm{d}k \, , 
$$
where $r \ge 0$ and $\alpha > 0$. It's evident that the integrand behaves as $\mathcal{O}\left( k^{-2} \right)$ as $k \to \infty$, indicating the convergence of the integral.

My attempted approach involved utilizing the classical expression of the zeroth-order Bessel function:
$$
J_0(u) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \exp \left(-iu \sin t \right) \, \mathrm{d} t
$$

I applied this expression to one as well as to both Bessel functions and attempted to evaluate them. Unfortunately, my efforts have not led to a successful result.

If anyone here can offer guidance or provide hints that might assist in evaluating this integral, I would greatly appreciate it.

> **E D I T**

Based on numerical tests, it appears that for $\alpha = 1$, $f(r)$ exhibits a proportionality to the modified Bessel function of the second kind, $K_0(r)$. The approximate proportionality coefficient appears to be around $1.2660658\dots$.

For other values of $\alpha$, the trend is less discernible. It's possible that the behavior is a combination of multiple modified Bessel functions of the second kind, but this is a speculative hypothesis derived from intuition and not necessarily a reflection of reality.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

A generalization of this integral appears on page 429 of the textbook [*A Treatise on the Theory of Bessel Functions*](https://archive.org/details/treatiseontheory00watsuoft/page/428/mode/2up), namely

$$\small \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{x^{2}+\alpha^{2}} \, J_{\mu} (\beta x) \left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi(\mu-\nu)}{2} \right)J_{\nu}(rx) + \sin \left(\frac{\pi(\mu-\nu)}{2} \right)Y_{\nu}(rx) \right) \, \mathrm dx = I_{\mu}(\beta \alpha) K_{\nu}(r \alpha)  $$ where $r \ge \beta >0$, and $\mu$ and $\nu$ are nonnegative real parameters such that $\mu > \nu -2$.

---

As in my [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4791409/16033), we can exploit properties of the [Hankel function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Hankel_functions:_H(1)%CE%B1,_H(2)%CE%B1).

Let $H_{0}^{(1)}(z)$ be the Hankel function of first kind of order zero defined as $$H_{0}^{(1)}(z) = J_{0}(z) + i Y_{0}(z), $$ where $Y_{0}(z)$ is the [Bessel function of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_second_kind:_Y%CE%B1) of order zero.

The principal branch of $H_{0}^{(1)}(z)$ has a branch cut on the negative real axis.

Since  $$Y_{0}(xe^{i \pi})=  Y_{0}(x) + 2i J_{0}(x),  \quad x >0,$$ it follows that

$$H_{0}^{(1)}(xe^{i \pi}) = - J_{0}(x) + iY_{0}(x), \quad x >0. $$

And since $\frac{x}{x^{2}+\alpha^{2}}$ is an odd function, we have $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{x^{2}+\alpha^{2}} \,   J_{0}(x)  J_{0}(rx) \, \mathrm dx = \frac{1}{2} \, \Re \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x}{x^{2}+\alpha^{2}} \,  H_{0}^{(1)} (x)  J_{0}(rx) \, \mathrm dx,$$ where the integration form $-\infty$ to $0$ is done on the upper side of the branch cut.

Now let's integrate the function $$f(z) = \frac{z}{z^{2}+\alpha^{2}} \,  H_{0}^{(1)}(z) J_{0}(rz), \quad 0 < r \le 1 \, ,  $$ around a contour consisting of the upper side of the branch cut from $-R$ to $-\epsilon$, a small clockwise- oriented semicircle about the origin, the real axis from $\epsilon$ to $R$, and the upper half of the circle $|z|=R$.

Since $\lim_{z \to 0} f(z) = 0$, the contribution from the small semicircle about the origin vanishes as $\epsilon \to 0$.

And as $|z| \to \infty$ in the upper half plane,  $|f(z)|$ is asymptotic to $$\frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{r}} \frac{e^{(r-1)\Im(z)}}{|z|^{2}}. $$

(See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Asymptotic_forms).)

Since $0 < r \le 1$, the integral vanishes on the upper half of the circle $|z|=R$ as $R \to \infty$ (by the estimation lemma), and we have $$ \begin{align} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x}{x^{2}+\alpha^{2}} \, H_{0}^{(1)} (x) J_{0}(rx) \, \mathrm dx &= 2 \pi i \operatorname*{Res}_{z=i \alpha} f(z) \\ &= 2 \pi i \lim_{z \to i \alpha} \frac{z}{z+i \alpha} \, H_{0}^{(1)}(z)  J_{0}(rz) \\ &= i \pi \, H_{0}^{(1)}(i \alpha)J_{0}(i r \alpha) \\ &\overset{(\spadesuit)}{=} i \pi \left(\frac{2K_{0}(\alpha)}{i \pi} \right) I_{0}(r \alpha) \\&= 2 K_{0}(\alpha) I_{0}(r \alpha). \end{align}$$

Equating the real parts on both sides of the equation, we have $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{x^{2}+ \alpha^{2}} \, J_{0}(x) J_{0}(rx) \, \mathrm dx = K_{0}(\alpha) I_{0}(r \alpha), \quad 0 < r \le 1. $$

This result also holds for $r=0$.

---

$\spadesuit$ https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.27#E8

---

To show that $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{x^{2}+ \alpha^{2}} \, J_{0}(x) J_{0}(rx) \, \mathrm dx = I_{0}(\alpha) K_{0}(r \alpha), \quad r \ge 1,  $$ integrate $$g(z) = \frac{z}{z^{2}+\alpha^{2}} \, J_{0}(z) H_{0}^{(1)}(rz) $$ around the same contour.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. Suppose now that we have $J_2(kr)$ instead of $J_0(kr)$ in the integrand. What I get for $r \ge 1$ is $2K_0(\alpha)I_1(\alpha r)/(\alpha r) - I_0(\alpha) K_0(\alpha r)$ but when using exemplary numerical values I do not get the same results. Any thoughts why?

Comment: @preuss  Then the contribution from the small semicircle about the origin doesn't vanish in the limit.  I'm getting $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{x^{2}+\alpha^{2}} \, J_{0}(x) J_{2}(rx) \, \mathrm dx = - I_{0}(\alpha) K_{2}(r \alpha) + \frac{2}{\alpha^{2}r^{2}}, \quad r \ge 1. $$

Comment: That's brilliant. Thanks a lot for your help in all of that.Very much appreciated!

Comment: Nice expression. But it looks like this is true only when $\mu \ge \nu$.

Comment: For $\mu < \nu$, one has to subtract the PV as does in an answer you provided here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4789720/int-0-infty-fracuu2-sigma2-j-4m-u-mathrmd-u-k-4m-si/4791409#4791409. I can now obtain expression for any value of $\mu$ and $\nu$ thanks to your insight.

Comment: @preuss    Thanks for the bounty.  You are correct.  We need restrictions on $\mu$ and $\nu$ so that the integral on the small semicircle vanishes as $\epsilon \to 0$.  Basically what we need is for $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{z^{\color{red}{2}}}{z^{2}+\alpha^{2}} J_{\mu}(\beta z) H_{\nu}^{(1)}(rz) =0$ to hold. If $\mu$ and $\nu$ are nonnegative real values, we need $\mu > \nu -2$.

Answer (score 2):

Using CAS like **Maple** give me:

$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{k J_0(k) J_0(k r)}{k^2+\alpha ^2} \, dk=I_0(r \alpha ) K_0(\alpha ) \theta (1-r)+I_0(\alpha ) K_0(r \alpha ) \theta (-1+r)$$

where:

$\theta (r)$ is Heaviside theta function.

$K_0(\alpha )$ is modified Bessel function of the second kind.

$I_0(\alpha )$ is modified Bessel function of the first kind.

**Maple 2023.2** code:

`inttrans:-hankel(BesselJ(0, k)/(alpha^2 + k^2), k, r, 0)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Which Maple version do you use? Mine is 2021 and it does not know how to deal with it. Same for Mathematica.

Comment: @preuss It's **2023.2**

Comment: I rectify: yes, 2021 does it as well when using inttrans. Thanks for pointing out this use. It works now and i am happy.

Comment: It works for me with Maple 2020.2